# Strange while loop tuple

Tags: javascript, parsing

I'm writing a JavaScript parser and while testing it on the prototype.js library, it threw up an error on this code:

line 4000:

```
while ( (chunker.exec(""), m = chunker.exec(soFar)) !== null ) {
    soFar = m[3];

    parts.push( m[1] );

    if ( m[2] ) {
        extra = m[3];
        break;
    }
}
```

I reduced it down to this:

```
while ( (a, b) == c ) {}
```

Is this really valid JavaScript? According to ECMA-262, a while loop has this syntax:

```
while ( Expression ) Statement
```

What sort of expression is `(a, b) == c`?  I didn't think tuples were supported in JavaScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not a tuple; that's the [comma operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.14) (also see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)). The comma operator evaluates the first operand and then the second operand and yields the value of the second.

Comment: Ah, this makes more sense.  I just checked ECMA-262 and it looks like I skipped over the comma operator.  Thanks!